# How can I make any mesh be filled with smoke?

Tags: smoke-simulation, shadows, volumetrics

I tried putting volume scatter and other nodes into the volume output in the node tree of a monkey but it creates a cube of volume around that monkey, how can I make it so it's like a monkey shaped cloud. Using Blender 2.83

Answer (score 2):

If you're using *Eevee*, volumetrics nodes won't work as they work for *Cycles*, they will be shaped into cubes.

Since 2.91, though, you can create a volume empty (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Volume > Empty*), and give it a *Mesh to Volume* modifier, with your object (here, your monkey) as *Target*. It will create a smoke that follows the shape of the *Target*:

[image]

Make your Suzane invisible. You can give your empty a material, by default it will be a *Principled Volume* plugged into the *Volume* socket of the *Material Output*. You can change the color or density of the volume:

[image]

Also, play with the parameters of the *Render > Volumetrics* panel, as it affects the quality of the volume:

[image]